# CustomExceptionHandler accepting too many exceptions

Tags: java, jsf

I've implemented a custom exception handler for my Faces, but it's absorbing the errors generated when there is an issue with the actual XHTML. How can I filter these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in you exception handler if the exception is type of FacesException
That will give you the abillity to fitlter by exception type

Try this ...

```
Throwable rootCause = getRootCause(throwable);
if (FacesException.class.isAssignableFrom(rootCause.getClass()))
{
   // perform sepecfic logic 
   // maybe you dont want to handle this exception
}
```